# Unable to change the fonts of the legend in QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.8

I'm running QGIS 2.8.0-Wien on my Ubuntu box and came across odd behaviour of print composer. When adding a legend - I'm unable to change the font size of the title and items.

Bizarrely - in the other legend I can do that perfectly fine.

What can be causing such behaviour?

The project was first created in older version of QGIS and I opened and saved it under 2.8 version (if that matters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue which is already fixed http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12233

Please update to 2.8.1.